# conversion excel to xml

Tags: c#, xml, excel

how to create xml with predefine schema from excel workbook?

Comment: Did you have any programming language or framework in mind?

Answer (score 0):

There is one trick. You can create **XSL** (style sheet) to convert your **XML** to simple **HTML** mark-up. Transform it using `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()` and save it with **XLS** (Excel Spreadsheet) extension. It will be opened by MS Excel and all Excel functionality will be available. As far as I know this is the optimal solution if you really just need to quickly dump data so it can be opened in Excel afterwards.

Comment: i want to convert excel to xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that might help you, i didn´t understand your problem so much. Simply put your filename and the xls is generated with the data in the dataset.

```
    public static void exportToExcel(DataSet source, string fileName)
    {

        System.IO.StreamWriter excelDoc;

        excelDoc = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
        const string startExcelXML = "<xml version>\r\n<Workbook " +
              "xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"\r\n" +
              " xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"\r\n " +
              "xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-    microsoft-com:office:" +
              "excel\"\r\n xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:" +
              "office:spreadsheet\">\r\n <Styles>\r\n " +
              "<Style ss:ID=\"Default\" ss:Name=\"Normal\">\r\n " +
              "<Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\"/>\r\n <Borders/>" +
              "\r\n <Font/>\r\n <Interior/>\r\n <NumberFormat/>" +
              "\r\n <Protection/>\r\n </Style>\r\n " +
              "<Style ss:ID=\"BoldColumn\">\r\n <Font " +
              "x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Bold=\"1\"/>\r\n </Style>\r\n " +
              "<Style     ss:ID=\"StringLiteral\">\r\n <NumberFormat" +
              " ss:Format=\"@\"/>\r\n </Style>\r\n <Style " +
              "ss:ID=\"Decimal\">\r\n <NumberFormat " +
              "ss:Format=\"0.0000\"/>\r\n </Style>\r\n " +
              "<Style ss:ID=\"Integer\">\r\n <NumberFormat " +
              "ss:Format=\"0\"/>\r\n </Style>\r\n <Style " +
              "ss:ID=\"DateLiteral\">\r\n <NumberFormat " +
              "ss:Format=\"mm/dd/yyyy;@\"/>\r\n </Style>\r\n " +
              "</Styles>\r\n ";
        const string endExcelXML = "</Workbook>";

        int rowCount = 0;
        int sheetCount = 1;
        /*
       <xml version>
       <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
       xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
       xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
       xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
       <Styles>
       <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
         <Borders/>
         <Font/>
         <Interior/>
         <NumberFormat/>
         <Protection/>
       </Style>
       <Style ss:ID="BoldColumn">
         <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
       </Style>
       <Style ss:ID="StringLiteral">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
       </Style>
       <Style ss:ID="Decimal">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="0.0000"/>
       </Style>
       <Style ss:ID="Integer">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="0"/>
       </Style>
       <Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="mm/dd/yyyy;@"/>
       </Style>
       </Styles>
       <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
       </Worksheet>
       </Workbook>
       */
        excelDoc.Write(startExcelXML);
        excelDoc.Write("<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet" + sheetCount + "\">");
        excelDoc.Write("<Table>");
        excelDoc.Write("<Row>");
        for (int x = 0; x < source.Tables[0].Columns.Count; x++)
        {
            excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"BoldColumn\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">");
            excelDoc.Write(source.Tables[0].Columns[x].ColumnName);
            excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
        }
        excelDoc.Write("</Row>");
        foreach (DataRow x in source.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            rowCount++;
            //if the number of rows is > 64000 create a new page to continue output

            if (rowCount == 64000)
            {
                rowCount = 0;
                sheetCount++;
                excelDoc.Write("</Table>");
                excelDoc.Write(" </Worksheet>");
                excelDoc.Write("<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet" + sheetCount + "\">");
                excelDoc.Write("<Table>");
            }
            excelDoc.Write("<Row>"); //ID=" + rowCount + "

            for (int y = 0; y < source.Tables[0].Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                System.Type rowType;
                rowType = x[y].GetType();
                switch (rowType.ToString())
                {
                    case "System.String":
                        string XMLstring = x[y].ToString();
                        XMLstring = XMLstring.Trim();
                        XMLstring = XMLstring.Replace("&", "&");
                        XMLstring = XMLstring.Replace(">", ">");
                        XMLstring = XMLstring.Replace("<", "<");
                        excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"StringLiteral\">" +
                                       "<Data ss:Type=\"String\">");
                        excelDoc.Write(XMLstring);
                        excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        //Excel has a specific Date Format of YYYY-MM-DD followed by  

                        //the letter 'T' then hh:mm:sss.lll Example 2005-01-31T24:01:21.000

                        //The Following Code puts the date stored in XMLDate 

                        //to the format above

                        DateTime XMLDate = (DateTime)x[y];
                        string XMLDatetoString = ""; //Excel Converted Date

                        XMLDatetoString = XMLDate.Year.ToString() +
                             "-" +
                             (XMLDate.Month < 10 ? "0" +
                             XMLDate.Month.ToString() : XMLDate.Month.ToString()) +
                             "-" +
                             (XMLDate.Day < 10 ? "0" +
                             XMLDate.Day.ToString() : XMLDate.Day.ToString()) +
                             "T" +
                             (XMLDate.Hour < 10 ? "0" +
                             XMLDate.Hour.ToString() : XMLDate.Hour.ToString()) +
                             ":" +
                             (XMLDate.Minute < 10 ? "0" +
                             XMLDate.Minute.ToString() : XMLDate.Minute.ToString()) +
                             ":" +
                             (XMLDate.Second < 10 ? "0" +
                             XMLDate.Second.ToString() : XMLDate.Second.ToString()) +
                             ".000";
                        excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"DateLiteral\">" +
                                     "<Data ss:Type=\"DateTime\">");
                        excelDoc.Write(XMLDatetoString);
                        excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
                        break;
                    case "System.Boolean":
                        excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"StringLiteral\">" +
                                    "<Data ss:Type=\"String\">");
                        excelDoc.Write(x[y].ToString());
                        excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
                        break;
                    case "System.Int16":
                    case "System.Int32":
                    case "System.Int64":
                    case "System.Byte":
                        excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"Integer\">" +
                                "<Data ss:Type=\"Number\">");
                        excelDoc.Write(x[y].ToString());
                        excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
                        break;
                    case "System.Decimal":
                    case "System.Double":
                        excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"Decimal\">" +
                              "<Data ss:Type=\"Number\">");
                        excelDoc.Write(x[y].ToString());
                        excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
                        break;
                    case "System.DBNull":
                        excelDoc.Write("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"StringLiteral\">" +
                              "<Data ss:Type=\"String\">");
                        excelDoc.Write("");
                        excelDoc.Write("</Data></Cell>");
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw (new Exception(rowType.ToString() + " not handled."));
                }
            }
            excelDoc.Write("</Row>");
        }
        excelDoc.Write("</Table>");
        excelDoc.Write(" </Worksheet>");
        excelDoc.Write(endExcelXML);
        excelDoc.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some data in excel and want to convert them to xml then you should have a suitable XML Schema definition. I'm assuming you do have a suitable schema, then you just have to follow few simple steps in excel which will convert it to xml. let me know, If you are looking for the steps on how to achieve this in excel... Hope you are having latest versions of Microsoft office..