# Excel to XML conversion

Tags: excel, export-to-xml, xmlconvert, vba

I want to convert Excel to XML using Excel.
I am able to map Excel with XML.
Now, I enter the records in Mapped Excel.
Next I click on **export** but pop-up appears with message :

> Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not exportable.

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/iwot39.jpg]

```
<ItemList>
  <Item UnitOfMeasure="EACH" ItemID="asdes123" ItemGroupCode="44" OrganizationCode="ABC">
    <PrimaryInformation IsShippingAllowed="Y" CostCurrency="USD" ShortDescription="asde" IsDeliveryAllowed="Y" Status="3000" UnitCost="0" Description="1q2w" IsPickupAllowed="Y"/>
    <InventoryParameters TimeSensitive="N" LeadTime="0" TagControlFlag="N" ATPRule="DEFAULT_ATP" IsSerialTracked="Y"/>
    <AdditionalAttributeList>
      <AdditionalAttribute Value="N" Name="Returnable"/>
      <AdditionalAttribute Value="N" Name="Consumable"/>
    </AdditionalAttributeList>
    <Extn ExtnLPNType="P"/>
  </Item>
</ItemList>
```

Please help me resolve this.
If you know other ways of doing this like using **macro** or etc, Kindly share.

Similar question [conversion excel to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192618/conversion-excel-to-xml)

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded the example XML and Mapped Excel-[Example](http://uploading.com/files/1641da71/example.zip/)(it ll take few sec before you can start downloading the file-sorry for that)

Also I have figured out the problem. Check this part of XML:

```
<AdditionalAttributeList>
  <AdditionalAttribute Value="N" Name="Returnable"/>
  <AdditionalAttribute Value="N" Name="Consumable"/>
</AdditionalAttributeList>
```

Tag **AdditionalAttribute** is repeated which on exporting leads to duplicate map for same attribute.
There must be a way to resolve this.

**Possible workaround**
changing tag name -ex: AdditionalAttribute11 during mapping and after exporting ***search and replace all***
  **AdditionalAttribute11** with **AdditionalAttribute** using "**notepad++**".
 
Kindly suggest.